# Kotlin type inference fails for guava TreeMultimap

Tags: guava, kotlin

I have:

```
data class Edge(val spec: String, val weight: Int)
private val graph: SortedSetMultimap<String, Edge> = TreeMultimap.create()
```

The call to create() is an error:

MapCrawler.kt: (63, 71): Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is TreeMultimap<(???..???), (???..???)>! but SortedSetMultimap was expected

If I change it to be a

```
SortedSetMultimap<String, String>
```

it works fine (no issues with the type inference).  In other words, this line compiles just fine:

```
private val graph: SortedSetMultimap<String, String> = TreeMultimap.create()
```

What is it about the Edge class that messes up the type inference, and how do I fix it?

Comment: What fails exactly? From the error it looks like you failed to comply with the type rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass two comparator implementation to `create` function. 
Have a look at following snippet:

```
private val graph:SortedSetMultimap<String, Food> = TreeMultimap.create(Comparator<String> { str1, str2 -> 0
        // compare string here
    }, Comparator<Food> { edge1, edge2 -> 0
        // compare Edge object here
    })
```

I have tested this it works. You can remove data type (`:SortedSetMultimap<String, Food>`) as assignment statement can infer which type of value is being returned.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, my question was missing some generics.  If I change it to SortedSetMultimap<String, String> then the type inference works fine.  It's the Edge class that it doesn't like.  I have reformatted my question so that it's clearer.

Comment: No, it doesn't work.  Obviously I tried that before.  It gives me private constructor TreeMultimap<K : Any!, V : Any!>(keyComparator: Comparator<in String!>!, valueComparator: Comparator<in MapCrawler.Edge!>!, multimap: Multimap<out String!, out MapCrawler.Edge!>!) defined in com.google.common.collect.TreeMultimap.   Why even bother trying to answer the question if you're not going to test your answer?

Comment: I can't check because i will have to setup an app to use `TreeMultimap` from guava lib that i dont have time to do. I thought it might help you so i answered.

Comment: Hey @user3562927 check updated answer, this time i have tested that snippet, sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: Not exactly what I was hoping for, but it works well enough, so thank you!